# Not authorized for requested resource when already logged in to Identity server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, federated-identity, thinktecture-ident-server

I have Identity server running locally with self signed SSL certificate, and RP that doesn't use HTTPS, when I try logging in for the first time(without being already logged in on IdentityServer) everything goes fine, I get authorized and redirected to my RP

Then I log out in my RP, but user is still logged in on IdentityServer. When I try to login agian from my RP I get:

**You are currenty logged in as alice, but you requested a resource that you were not authorized for. Either provide credentials that do have access or contact your administrator to grant you access.**

Althought user is in correct role I tried disableing option: 
**Only users in the "IdentityServerUsers" role are able to request tokens**
But that didn't help.

I checked thumbprint, and it matches. Can someone suggest me what might be wrong here?

Comment: How did you signout from RP?HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut ?